# Magento 2 admin url gives error - Class Magento\Authorization\Model\RoleFactory does not exist

Tags: admin, magento2, url

I have installed magento 2 on a local network (for example 192.200.200.200, and it is a virtual machine)

i was having some permission problems, had to run sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

to create all css js required; public area looks fine but when i try to access mi admin url (192.200.200.200/admin_stuff) i get an error which is this: http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/2DKT

Could be a permission problem? right now all folder and file are own by root but folers var pub and app/etc are owned by the web user (www-data) with the right permissons

or maybe some file where not copied?

Comment: You try set permission 777(755) for `<magento_dir>/var` folder

Comment: Still gives the same error :(

Answer (score 4):

In my case, it was the issue with `var/generation` directory. Magento 2 creates Factory classes and stores in this directory.

I cleared `var/generation` directory and set it's ownership as that of `var/cache` and `var/page_cache` directory. And, now the issue is solved. I am able to login to admin again.

Answer (score 2):

`Magento\Authorization\Model\RoleFactory` refers to `Magento\Authorization\Model\Role` which should be located in `vendor/magento/module-authorization/Model/Role.php`. If this file is not available, than that's your problem.

Comment: The file is there, with this file permissions -rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 3066 nov 17 01:55 Role.php, this is not correct?

Answer (score 2):

I cleared cache and deployed again as follows, and finally was able to login:

```
sudo php -f bin/magento cache:clean

sudo rm -rf pub/static/*; 
sudo rm -rf var/*/*; 
sudo php -f bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US en_CA

sudo chown -R :www-data .
sudo find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
sudo find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
sudo find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
```

If directory owner is different, use it instead of "www-data".

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me after removing var/generation and login again. later var/generation created automatically.